# Laravel 5.4 Route [login] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hi I have following route and constructor in my controller i want to check if user is authenticated or not if not then redirect to /warehouse/login page. but for some reasons i am getting Route [login] not defined error.

I am migrating my functions from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.4

Constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if (!Auth::check()) {
                $url = URL::current();
                $routeName = Route::currentRouteName();

                if ($routeName != "AdminLogin" && $routeName != 'admin') {
                    Session::put('pre_admin_login_url', $url);
                }
                return redirect('/warehouse/login');
            }

            return $next($request);

        }, array('except' => array('WarehouseAdminLogin', 'WarehouseAdminVerify')));


    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/warehouse', 'WarehouseController@index');
Route::get('/warehouse/login', array('as' => 'WarehouseAdminLogin', 'uses' => 'WarehouseController@login'));
```

Comment: Your error comes from within `$this->middleware('auth');` 
I guess you don't have `Auth::routes();` within your routes file.

Comment: @nakov if i remove that then getting the page isn't redirecting properly error.

Comment: so as I said, it is because you are missing the routes in your route file.

Comment: @nakov can you please write here which route i am missing ?

Comment: `Auth::routes();` in your routes file. This defines those `login`, `register` and so on routes which are used within the `Auth` middleware.

Comment: if you want to use a manual authentication follow this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: the problem is that you have not a *route* named **login**. This error is caused by:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

because this code in the **auth** **middleware**:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

So what to do is **remove auth middleware** and try again or make a route with login name.

Comment: try this @danishjamshed

Comment: I tried removing $this->middleware('auth'); but now getting the page is not redirecting properly error @Mahdi

Comment: keep the middleware and just change the name of **WarehouseAdminLogin** route to **login**
@DanishJamshed

Comment: this is working login page is showing but now when i enter username password its redirecting me back to login page.

Comment: Login form is submitting to verify function

Answer (score 0):

You didnt define your login function.

make a function
`public function login()
{'your code'}`

in your **WarehouseController**

Comment: I have  a  login function in WarehouseController.

Comment: ok, I didnt see that in your code, then you need to check if you have Auth::routes(); in your web.php. And login is route::post not get. Goodluck :)